# Show python object name

Tags: python, django, object, self

In the django admin page, everything is just showing 'xxx object' and not the 
name that i write in the model:

```
class categoria(models.Model):
    nomeCategoria = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    imagemCategoria = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
   return self.nomeCategoria

class post(models.Model):
    tituloPost = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='tituloPost')
    textoPost = models.TextField()
    textoTagPost = models.TextField()
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(categoria)
    enviadoNewsletter = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
   return 'Post: ' + self.tituloPost
```

I'm using python 3.4

I also tried to put this code in admin.py:

```
class categoriaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nomeCategoria','imagemCategoria')

admin.site.register(categoria, categoriaAdmin)
```

but this only show the right name in the list.
I think the point of the **str** is to show the right field everywhere, or am I wrong?

I'm new in this , sorry about my english and hope someone can help.

Comment: @iCodez, I rolled back your edit because the indentation issue *was* the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**str** or better yet **unicode** need to be properly spaced over, so that the class has the method, not the module. Also, you should probably use titles for model classes (i.e. class Categoria)

```
class categoria(models.Model):
    nomeCategoria = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    imagemCategoria = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.nomeCategoria

class post(models.Model):
    tituloPost = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='tituloPost')
    textoPost = models.TextField()
    textoTagPost = models.TextField()
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(categoria)
    enviadoNewsletter = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
       return 'Post: ' + self.tituloPost
```